# jquery clone id update

Tags: jquery

I am trying to clone radio groups using jquery. My cloning code is:

```
$("#btnAddAnotherLocation").live("click", function(){
    cloneIndexLocation++;

    $("#clonedInputLocation0").clone()
    .appendTo("#clonedInputsLocation")
    .attr("id", "clonedInputLocation" + cloneIndexLocation)
    .find("*").each(function(){
         var id = this.id || "";
         var match = id.match(regex) || [];

         if(match.length == 5){
             this.id = match[1]+(cloneIndexLocation);
         }
     }).end();
});
```

My cloneDiv content is:

```
<div id="clonedInputLocation0" class="clonedInputLocation" style="display: none;">
    <div class="formLocationWrapper">
         <label class="labelRadioBlack labelContainsInput" for="locationInNear0">
             <input name="locationInNearRadio[]" id="locationInNear0" value="" type="radio" />
             In or near
         </label>
      <div class="inNearTextWrapper">
      <input class="myWirrlMediumFormField" type="text" name="txtLocationInNear[]" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="formLocationWrapper">
    <label class="labelRadioBlack labelContainsInput" for="locationAnywhereIn0">
         <input name="locationInNearRadio[]" id="locationAnywhereIn0" value="" type="radio" checked="checked" />
              Anywhere in
    </label>
</div>
    <div class="" id="clonedInputLocationRemove0">
        <a href="javascript: void(0);">Remove location</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sorry about it looking messy, it is actually a lot cleaner in my editor.

The problem isn't with cloning the actual content, this is working fine. The issue is that I need to update the radio groups name to be locationInNearRadio[cloneIndexLocation] and the ID's and the FOR attributes to be named locationInNearcloneIndexLocation where cloneIndexLocation is the next increment.

I have this code working for a group of select fields which updates all ID's to the clonedIndex number but for some reason I cant get the same code to even update the radio groups ID's.

Cheers

Comment: What does your regex look like and are you sure that using +1 with a string is incrementing the number or just adding the "1" to the end of the id? A demo on jsFiddle.net would be much more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var cloneIndexLocation = 0;
            var clonedInputLocation = $('<div></div>').append($("#clonedInputLocation0").clone()).html();


            $("#btnAddAnotherLocation").live("click", function () {
                //cloneIndexLocation++;  //If u remove the locatoin then index has to be changed.

                //Or

                cloneIndexLocation = $('#clonedInputsLocations div').length;

                $(clonedInputLocation.replace(/collectionIndex/gi, cloneIndexLocation)).appendTo("#clonedInputsLocations");
                $('#clonedInputsLocations div').show();
            });
        });    
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!--where you need to replace by cloneIndexLocation use ( collectionIndex ) word in there. it wiil replace it by number.-->
    <div id="clonedInputLocation0" class="clonedInputLocation" style="display: none;">
        <div class="formLocationWrapper">
            <label class="labelRadioBlack labelContainsInput" for="locationInNear0">
                <input name="locationInNearRadio[collectionIndex]" id="locationInNear0" value=""
                    type="radio" />
                In or near
            </label>
            <div class="inNearTextWrapper">
                <input class="myWirrlMediumFormField" type="text" name="txtLocationInNear[collectionIndex]"
                    value="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="formLocationWrapper">
            <label class="labelRadioBlack labelContainsInput" for="locationAnywhereIn0">
                <input name="locationInNearRadio[collectionIndex]" id="locationAnywhereIn0" value=""
                    type="radio" checked="checked" />
                Anywhere in
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="" id="clonedInputLocationRemove0">
            <a href="javascript: void(0);">Remove location</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="btnAddAnotherLocation" value="AddAnotherLocation" />
    <div id="clonedInputsLocations">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: first instal firebug addons in firefox. run the code in firefox browser. and press f12 you will see the changed collectionIndex to integer.